# C++ Inheritance operator<<

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism

I have a few objects (classes) that all inherit from a base class Structure. These objects all print differently as they have different member variables but share common functions.

I want to be able to have a list of structures and print them without having to cast them back into their specific object, ie: Structure -> Building.

Is this possible in C++?

```
class Structure
{

};

class Building : public Structure
{
public:
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& o, const Building &b)
    {
        return o << b.m_windows.size() << b.m_doors.size();
    }
protected:
    Windows m_windows;
    Doors m_doors;
};

class Statue : public Structure
{
public:
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& o, const Statue &s)
    {
        return o << s.m_type;
    }
protected:
    StatueType m_type;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Structure struct* = new Building();
    std::cout << struct << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

Error:
error: cannot bind 'std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}' lvalue to 'std::basic_ostream<char>&&'
     std::cout << struct << std::endl;
```

**Edit:**

I've isolated the issue in my own code, here is a compilable version (C11). The problem is that I am using further inheritance and the output of my command is:

```
CORRECT_VALUE<random address>
8.8.8.80x804c504
```

I'm not sure why it appends that random address?

http://pastebin.com/81ubU0yX

Comment: You probably meant `Structure* struct`, not  `Structure struct*`?

Comment: @zenith Will either compile? :)

Comment: dont use struct as varaible name, because it is reserved word. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword

Comment: @NeilKirk Not really.

Comment: @NeilKirk Could you please look at my update. I further inherit from the Building/Statue classes but the printing causes a random address to be appended.

Comment: @critikull4 The issue is in your `operator<<`. See how it differs from the one in Neil's answer. You are printing the address of the stream.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a virtual output function and call it within the `operator <<`. Override this output function in your derived classes.

```
class Structure
{
public:
    virtual ~Structure() {}
    virtual std::ostream& StreamOut(std::ostream& o) const { return o; }

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& o, const Structure &s)
    {
        return s.StreamOut(o);
    }
};

class Building : public Structure
{
public:
    virtual std::ostream& StreamOut(std::ostream& o) const
    {
        return o << m_windows.size() << m_doors.size();
    }
protected:
    Windows m_windows;
    Doors m_doors;
};

class Statue : public Structure
{
public:
    virtual std::ostream& StreamOut(std::ostream& o) const
    {
        return o << m_type;
    }
protected:
    StatueType m_type;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::unique_ptr<Structure> myStruct(new Building());
    std::cout << *myStruct << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: @critikull4 In the general case, these are simple examples of [Inversion of Control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control) and specifically the [Template Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern), very useful tools to understand in general for these kind of "base class defines algorithmic functionality, subclasses define implementation" problems.

Comment: @critikull4 It should be `return c.output(o);`